# How to extract text and images from html?

Tags: android

I am using this to extract SPAN tags and tell how many there is.

```
ublic class HtmlparserExampleActivity extends Activity {
String outputtext;
  TagFindingVisitor visitor;
  Parser parser = null;
private static final String TAG = "TVGuide";

private static final boolean D = true;

TextView outputTextView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




     outputTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);


    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");


    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "In doInBackground");

        parser = new Parser ("http://www.johandegraeve.net/android");

            String tags[] = { "SPAN" };

          visitor = new TagFindingVisitor(tags);

            try {

                parser.visitAllNodesWith (visitor);

                outputtext =  "there are " + visitor.getTags(0).length + " SPAN nodes.\n";

                for (int i = 0;i<visitor.getTags(0).length;i++) {

                    outputtext = outputtext + visitor.getTags(0)[i].toHtml();  


                }

              outputTextView.setText(outputtext);

            } catch (ParserException e) {

                if(D) Log.e(TAG, "Exception in +++ ON CREATE +++ \n" +

                        "parser.visitAllNodesWith (visitor) failed\n" +

                        e.toString());

            }

    } catch (ParserException e1) {

        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "Exception in +++ ON CREATE +++ \n" +

                "creation of parser failed\n" +

                e1.toString());
```

}
        }

}

How do i change this to get the text and images and display just the text and images in their wigdets? Using this code?

EDIT: What would be the tags for a html page like this to get the text and the images URLs?

http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html

EDIt: Source code.

```
public class HtmlparserExampleActivity extends Activity {
String outputtext;
  TagFindingVisitor visitor;
  Parser parser = null;
private static final String TAG = "TVGuide";



TextView outputTextView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    outputTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
    String id = "main-article-content";
    Document doc = null;

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
    Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag(id);  
    String[] temp1 = new String[99];;
    int i =0;
    for(Element element: elementsHtml)
    {

        temp1 = element.text();
        i++;
        outputTextView.setText(temp1[1]);

    }




}
```

}

I tried this, it didnt work. Maybe im doing something wrong. NO text showed up in the textview. But i seen some tags in the debug from the webpage.

Comment: See my edit....I hope this is what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSoup` parser and parse the elements by `tag`. JSoup is very efficient and simple for these kind of small parsings.

Edit: I dont know your situation but I'll give a try:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("someurl").get();
        Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
        Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");  <--- here you specify the html tag where is the text is located
        String[] temp1 = new String[99];    
        int i =0;
        for(Element element: elementsHtml)
        {

            temp1[i] = element.text();
            i++;

        }
//After you have collected all the elements, you set the textview
```

More: Go the the page you want and view the page source and there you can search the content you want then see which tag/class/id you are going to use.

I've parsed the HTML for you:

```
try{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://movies.ign.com/articles/100/1002569p1.html").get();

        Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "main-article-content");

        for(Element element: elementsHtml)
        {
            Log.i("PARSED ELEMENTS:",URLDecoder.decode(element.text(), HTTP.UTF_8));
                 outputTextView.setText(element.text());


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is this the text you wanted to parse?

*08-11 21:08:02.095: INFO/PARSED ELEMENTS(200): It's the end of an era, as Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2 opens this week, bringing to a close the epic film series that has spanned eight films and ten years. To mark the occasion, we have decided to take another look at the wonderful characters in the series, once more ranking our Top 25. You'll notice some tweaks and changes to this list since we first ran it a couple of years ago, as we examined and re-evaluated all that we've seen of the characters. Before we reveal our picks, a quick word about the selection process...*

Comment: Ive looked at the cookbook example. But what do i use if i just want the text and images? Thats all? For example if i just wanted the text and images from this page?

Comment: I think there was a `.text()` method. Check http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text()

Comment: Im not really good with reading those api documents. They are confusing. Could you give me an example of parsing and getting all the text from this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing

Comment: Thanks alot! All i am trying to do is use the url to get some of the text on different webpages and put it in a TextView. Does your code reflect this?

Comment: The code will produce results as long as you specify the url and the HTML response contains the tag you specify in the `.getElementsByTag(tag);` method. Once you extract the text you can use it with your textview, of course.

Comment: I guess you try to get the main article, this is the html tags for it

`<div id="main-article-content">`. In this case you can use `doc.getElementById(id)` where `id="main-article-content";`

Or another good approach is to use `doc.getElementsByAttributeValue(key, value)` where `key="id"` and `value ="main-article-content"`

Comment: SO i just set the id as a string?

Comment: Yep, straight forward :D. `getElementById()` [and the other similar methods] accepts arguments of type String only.

Comment: And how to i set the temp1[i] to a text view?

Comment: `temp1` is array of strings, so you need to log all the elements of the array and then set the wanted element of the array for example `myTextView.setText(temp1[0]);`[assuming that desired content is in the first position of the `temp1`]. Bear in mind that exist another way to do this, i just gave you example.

Comment: Check out my new edit. With the code im using. It didn't display any text in the textview. But i seen some of the "DOC" debug logs.

Comment: No, no. You cant set ARRAY of STRINGS into textView you can only store single STRING. temp1[0] or temp1[1] represents one element of the array which is SINGLE STRING.

Comment: I change it to setText(tempt1[1]); still no luck

Comment: You have to set the text before you increment the `i`

Comment: Log the elements first. See if there is information. Then proceed with what you want `Log.i("data: ", element.text());`

Comment: Try another getting elements by something else, if you did by tag, do by id, or attribute...

Comment: Thats PERFECT! Exactly what i was looking for and wanted! SO for future references..Lets say i want to make a defualt parser for text and images. I have a list of html links, which ever one that is clicked is parsed for the text content and images. How would i go about created a defualt process like this?

Comment: Ow, thats a matter of logic, you need to know how the HTML is organized, not always all the pages has the same class names/id names/any-other-attributes. Its matter of logic, but you can do with methods from the JSoup class that look for matching expression. See these methods `getElementsByAttributeValueMatching(key, pattern)` and `getElementsByAttributeValueContaining(key, match)`. And in future tend to read, its for your own good :D Everyone does read the docs :D You barely find someone that will give you the entire implementation, tend to do things on your own with lil help

Comment: Your right man, Ill stop here then, so you think reading the docs will give me everything i need to do this?

Comment: Well, give you at least understanding :D

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski: Hi, mind answering to this please? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228406/extracting-text-from-web-pages-only-gives-the-url?noredirect=1#comment28464053_19228406

Answer (score 1):

You can try the JSoup parser.

http://jsoup.org/