# Extracting text from web pages only gives the URL

Tags: java, android, html, eclipse, jsoup

I am working on the following code:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction())) 
            {
                String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                
                try
                {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(text).get();
                    Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
                    Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");  
                    ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
                    
                    for(Element element: elementsHtml)
                    {
    
                        temp1.add( element.text());
    
                    }
                    
                    //Add all the text to the edit text
                    for(int i=0;i<temp1.size();i++)
                    {
                        textField.append(temp1.get(i));
                    }
                    
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
        
            }
```

This code uses JSoup library with Android code. I need to extract all the text from the webpage, and that is the purpose of the above code. But instead, what it does is getting the URL of the webpage and appending it to the text field and that's it.

And I need all the text. This code is targeting to "tr".

Why this is happening? How can I correct it?

### Update

I changed my code as below, and now I do not get anything!

```
 //Get the web page text if called from Share-Via
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction())) 
            {
                String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
                
                try
                {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(text).get();
                    Log.i("DOC", doc.toString().toString());
                    Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("tr");  
                    ArrayList<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
                    
                    for(Element element: elementsHtml)
                    {
    
                        temp1.add( element.text());
    
                    }
                    
                    //Add all the text to the edit text
                    for(int i=0;i<temp1.size();i++)
                    {
                        textField.append(temp1.get(i));
                    }
                    
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
        
            }
```

This is my manifest file code (only the required part) if it helps

```
<activity
            android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
            
        </activity>
```

Comment: That code should work. on which site you test it? Are you sure that the `getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);` works correct? Maybe put an Log output for this.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider: Lot of sites. I really don't understand this :(

Comment: @Artificial_Intelligence Christian has good point, output the website html, and see how many elements can be extracted with `doc.getElementsByTag("tr");` and improve your code. If you want to extract (i.e strip html tags) you can quickly do it with `Jsoup.parse(html).text()`.